# I want to call the balloon object that is destroyed when clicked and check that in the timer event function

Tags: c#, forms, oop, window

In click event in my code, when I click the balloon object, I want to check that it matches the result of the equation generated randomly.

For this problem I want to call the balloon object that is destroyed when clicked in the timer event and check that the destroyed object matches the answer or not.

I want to use the "balloon" object in timer event to check whether the popped balloon is equal to the result of the equation or not.

C# Winforms application

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    for (int h = 1; h <= 5; h++)
    {
            if(PopBalloon(v))
    }           
}

private void PopBalloon(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int num;
        
        if (GameOver == false)
        {
            var balloon = (PictureBox)sender;
            balloon.Top = r.Next(700, 1000);
            balloon.Left= r.Next(5,500);
        }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Can you elaborate what part is not working? Also, the code you show above either does not compile or you are showing a wrong overload of `PopBalloon`

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation my problem is solved now